# react-datepicker remove coloring of same day in other months

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

If you look at the default implementation of the react-datepicker the day of this month will be highlighted on every month. Is there a way to only highlight/color the day of the current month and not highlight this date in all other months?

If you look at the first image the 6 August is highlighted because it is the current date. But 6 September is also highlighted.

[image: This Month]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a custom css selector to disable background for all these dates.

```
.react-datepicker__day.react-datepicker__day--keyboard-selected {
  background: none;
  color: black;
}
```

Check this sandbox too

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-wqs7y

Comment: I don't seem to get it to work. My datepicker has a custom className "DatePicker". Maybe this is the problem? 
<DatePicker
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
          includeDates={this.state.allowedDates}
          highlightDates={this.state.allowedDates}
          className={styles.DatePicker}
          inputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
        />

Comment: hmm can you try with `!important` just in case? I have a codesandbox which is working

Comment: i updated the selector in order not to use `!important`.

Comment: Ok I got it to work. I added the code to the css of the component that contains the Datepicker. When I added the code to the css file of index.js it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Big Up! Thx to you

Comment: This solution saved lot of time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15):

After I realized this issue is related to the CSS class `.react-datepicker__day--keyboard-selected`, I did a quick search and found out we can fix this problem by disabling the keyboard navigation (if you don't need the keyboard navigation feature)

```
<DatePicker 
  selected={startDate} 
  onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
  disabledKeyboardNavigation
/>
```